# Butterworth high pass filter

Tags: highpass-filter, butterworth

My signal's base line is around 1. When I apply Butterworth high pass filter with cut off frequency Fc = 2Hz signal's base line drops to 0. My data are from the accelerometer. Is this behavior normal ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A high-pass filter removes low frequencies, and a constant baseline is the lowest frequency possible ("DC" = 0 Hz), so it will be completely removed and the baseline will become 0.

Answer (score 1):

Also, an accelerometer has a very flat frequency response till its (high frequent) resonance point.

But as the name gives away; the sensor provides you with **acceleration** data. If you want to know velocity, you need to integrate the signal once, and if you want to know displacement, you need to integrate the signal twice.

Each integration step adds a pole at zero and gives a drop-off of 6 dB per octave.